# How to compare a string to a const string in C++

Tags: c++, string, comparison, const-string

Let's say I have the following poc code:

```
const string& a = "hello";
string b = "l";

if(a.at(2) == b)
{
 // do stuff
}
```

I understand that there is no operator "==" that matches these operands. And, the way to fix it is by converting the value of the variable a into 'hello' (instead of double quotes) as char.

However, what if I have no choice but performing the comparison as shown in the code. Is it possible? Could you please provide any guidance or suggestions you might have on this issue.

Your responses are appreciated.

Comment: `const string a = "hello";`

Comment: `char b = 'l';`

Comment: Show the message that **this** code generates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const string& a = "hello";
string b = "l";

if (a[2] == b[0])
{
    // do stuff
}
```

a.at(2) is not string. when do b to b[0] problem solving.

Comment: I must have been hallucinating this entire time. Thanks for the enlightenment.

Answer (score 4):

You're comparing a `char` (to be specific a `const char`) and a `std::string`, of which there exists no overloaded comparison operator for ([`operator==`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_cmp)).

You have some options:

(1) compare `b`'s first character to the character you're wanting to compare to

```
string b = "l";
string a = "hello";
if(a[2] == b[0]) { /* .. */ }
```

(2) convert `a[2]` to a `std::string`

```
string b = "l";
string a = "hello";
if(string{a[2]} == b) { /* .. */ }
```

(3) let `b` be a `char`

```
char b = 'l';
string a = "hello";
if(a[2] == b) { /* .. */ }
```

Also, you should not construct a string object like this

```
const string& a = "hello";
```

unless you actually want to create a reference to another string object, e.g.

```
string x = "hello";
const string& a = x;
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed breakdown of those options. In my code, I'm actually passing "const string& a" as a function argument.